# In C# TryParse output is bool or int?

Tags: c#

I`m trying to understand, but this is not output @! If its bool , cant be signed to int, but if it is int, cant be signed to bool.
How to take and use the numeric value after successful TryParse ? Thks.

```
using System;

namespace TryParse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            bool s;
            int a = int.TryParse(input, out @@@ WHAT ???? );


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reading the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 5):

The documentation about int.TryParse is pretty clear to me. It returns a bool and needs an integer where it will store the result. So your code cannot be compiled

Instead the correct line should be the following

```
bool isAnInteger = Int32.TryParse(input, out int value);
```

Now you will get the conversion of *output* to an integer if it contains digits that can be interpreted as an integer and the return value will be true. If it is not possible the variable *value* will contain the default value for integers (0) and the returned value will be false.

Answer (score 3):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if(int.TryParse(input, out int a))
{
   //success
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
bool s;
int a ;
if(int.TryParse(input, out a)){
  //success
}
else{
 //failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply to convert bool to Int32:

```
int i;
bool b = int.TryParse(s, out i);

/* generate 4 bytes from single byte bool */
byte[] bytes = { BitConverter.GetBytes(b)[0], 0, 0, 0 };

/* convert 4 bytes to Int32 */
int n = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

EDIT:

Convert bool to Int64:

```
int i;
bool b = int.TryParse(s, out i);

/* generate 8 bytes from single byte bool */
byte[] bytes = { BitConverter.GetBytes(b)[0], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

/* convert 8 bytes to Int64 */
Int64 n = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
```